# What exactly is the output quaternion of slerp?

Tags: c, math, vector, quaternions

I'm trying to implement SLERP (described by Ken Shoemake in "Animating Rotation with Quaternion Curves)
I've read up on the topic on wikipedia (topic: quaternions, [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) and [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)) and other sites and also searched stackoverflow about this problem. It seems like I understand the theory behind it, but oversee one small detail. I will use w for the scalar value of the quaternion

So initially I have two 3D vectors. Each vector has a representation in two coordinate systems (C and C'). My goal is to find a third representation of these vectors in the system "halfway" the initial two. 
So what I do is I find the rotation matrix, which transform the vectors from C to C', which seems to work out quite fine. 
My next step is to transform this matrix into a quaternion, which also works.

Now my issue is with the formula of slerp, which is:

slerp(q1, q2; u) = ((sin(1-u) * t)/ (sin t)) * q1 + (sin(ut)/sin t) * q2

(sorry can't upload images yet for a better representation: see source 1)

so I guess here u = 0.5, q1 is the vector I would like to rotate (with w=0) and q2 equals the quaternion I calculated previously. Theta is calculated from the dotproduct of the normalized vector and the (already) normalized quaternion.

So what I expect is that I get back a vector, rotated either from C to the third coordinate system or from C' to the third coordinate system.

My issue now is, that I don't see, how I will get a vector and not a quaternion. Meaning, how is it possible, that I will get a quaternion with (w=0), as by simply multiplying q2 with this factor won't set w to 0. Or is it something else I will get from this function?

What am I overseeing here?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I figured it out. For someone with the same understanding problem:

slerp simply interpolates between two orientations, meaning between two actual rotations. So in my case, q1 is the quaternion corresponding to the identity matrix (so [1, 0, 0, 0]). q2 is the rotation. theta is still 0.5. 
With the quaternion I get from this, I have to calculate the rotation with q^-1 v q. Where v is my vector I want to rotate. This can be calculated using the Hamilton product.